# In the Witcher books does Ciri have a magical scream?

Tags: the-witcher

I've just watched the first episode of the NetFlix Witcher adaptation, and very good it is too though there was one plot device I'm unsure about.

In the adaptation, as in the books, Ciri is abducted by Cahir at the fall of Cintra. However in the adaptation she:

> escapes by using a magical scream to stun him. An earlier scene shows her rattling glasses by screaming.

In the game Witcher 3 there is one scene where she shows a similar power. It's at the siege of Kaer Morhen where she uses it against Eredin. However I don't recall any such power in the books. So my question is whether there is anywhere in the books that she uses a power like this.

Comment: Pavetta did something like that, but that's only occasion.

Comment: I haven't read the books, but it's not that Ciri has a *magic scream*, but instead she has a primal power (since she's a Source), and in stressful situations that power gets out of hand. In the series, this is shown with screaming, but in the books it might be something entirely different.

Comment: @Mithoron that's a very good point and I had forgotten that scene from A Question of Price. If you want to post that as an answer then I'd be happy to accept it, though I'll wait a day or two in case someone finds another reference.

Comment: @JohnRennie I mean, Ciri has the same power as Pavetta. Both woman are Sources.

Comment: @Roberto yes, but I asked if Ciri does that in the books because I recall no reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look as if this is going to attract an answer, so for completeness I will post a brief answer.

In the books there is no occasion when Ciri uses a power like the one shown in the Witcher series, but [as Mithoron points out in a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225046/in-the-witcher-books-does-ciri-have-a-magical-scream#comment615817_225046) her mother Pavetta does. This happens in the story [A Question of Price](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/A_Question_of_Price), and indeed this scene appears in one of the later episodes of the Netflix show.

So it looks as if the writers gave Ciri this power to explain how she escapes from Cahir. This seems reasonable since both Ciri and her mother are [Sources](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Source) and could quite reasonably have similar powers.

Comment: It later occurred to me that also Vereena - bruxa, had some magical scream attack, but, well, besides that and being hot chick she didn't have much in common with Ciri ;D